# Check if combobox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have two comboboxes. I want to know which combobox is selected. I want to do like below using ajax, jquery in a jsp file.

```
if(combobox1 selected)
{
  action 1
} 
if(combobox2 selected)
{
  action 2
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would it be this ? in this case you could know which was the last modified element. I used switch case because you could have several comboxes

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="my_combox" name="combox1">
    <option value="1">value 1</option>
    <option value="2">value 2</option>
    <option value="3">value 3</option>
    <option value="4">value 4</option>
  </select>
  <select class="my_combox" name="combox2">
    <option value="5">other value 1</option>
    <option value="6">other value 1</option>
    <option value="7">other value 1</option>
    <option value="8">other value 1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Script

```
var lastSelectedCombox = "";
$('.my_combox').on('change',function(e){
    lastSelectedCombox = $(this).attr('name');
    switch(lastSelectedCombox){
      case 'combox1':console.log('first combox');
          break;
      case 'combox2':console.log('second combox');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('any combox expected');
    }
})
```